# couchdb replace string works in temporary view, but not in permanent

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb

I am writing a coucdhdb view where I'm omitting units in a string (either "sec" or "seconds") and converting it to a number, before emitting the value.  I don't have control over how the data is stored.

My view looks like this:

```
"map" : "function(doc)
  {
    if (doc['Elapsed Time']){
      var x = +doc['Elapsed Time'].replace(/ sec.*/, "");
      emit([doc.User, doc.Date], x);
    }
```

It works correctly in the temporary view, but I get the following error when trying to PUT it using curl: {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}

If I try to save the view directly in the permanent view in Futon, it tells me:
JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object,
but all the {} match, and I've dinked with putting ',' in almost everywhere, but nothing works.

Are there special characters, or something else that I must avoid in a permanent view, that I don't when testing in a temp view?

Comment: OK got it.  You have to escape "/" and quotes in permanent views.  (Apparently not temporary ones)

Comment: Are you merely trying to get the number out of a string containing a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a regular expression for that just use the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt) function which does exactly what you want.

You'd just do it like this.

```js
"map": "function(doc) {
    if (doc['Elapsed Time']) {
      emit([doc.User, doc.Date], parseInt(doc['Elapsed Time'], 10));
    }
}"
```

*Note: I wrote `parseInt(doc['Elapsed Time'], 10)` where **10** is the radix which you should always define.*